# The vertices of the $n$-cube are painted in two colors

Tags: combinatorics

The vertices of the $n$-dimensional cube are painted in two colors. The number of vertices of each color is the same ($2^{n-1}$). Prove that  at least $2^{n-1}$ edges connect vertices of different colors.

Comment: Do you mean coloring in the graph-theoretical sense, i.e., coloring of the hypercube $Q_n$?

Comment: @ blazs: No, I mean arbitrary painting of hypercube.

Comment: Ok, just to make perfectly sure: you allow vertices connected by an edge to have the same color?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @grizzly Where did this problem come from?  What have you tried?

Comment: @Tad We discussed this problem on the forum [dxdy](http://dxdy.ru/topic98745.html) (in Russian). We tried to find a combinatorial solution. Today I knew that this problem was given for homework in the book: _Combinatorics_ by Naum Ya. Vilenkin et al (In Russian).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question can be phrased as follows: for any subset $S$ of $2^{n-1}$ vertices in the $n$-dimensional hypercube graph $H_n$, show that $|\delta(S)|\ge2^{n-1}$, where 
$$\delta(S) := \{(u,v)\mid u\in S, v\notin S\}$$
is the *boundary* of $S$.

It is a standard result of spectral graph theory that, for any subset $S$ of a graph $G$,
$$|\delta(S)| \ge \lambda_2 |S| (1-|S|/|V(G)|)$$
where $0=\lambda_1\le\lambda_2\le\cdots\le\lambda_{n-1}$ are the eigenvalues of the Laplacian of $G$.

Now, $H_n$ is the $n$-fold [(Cartesian) graph product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_product) of the graph $H_1$ having two vertices and one edge.  The eigenvalues of (the Laplacian of) $H_1$ are $0$ and $2$, and it follows that the eigenvalues of $H_n$ are $0, 2,\ldots, 2n$, each with multiplicity $\binom nk$. Thus, for $H_n$, we have $\lambda_2=2$; it follows that if $|S|=2^{n-1}$, we have
$$|\delta(S)| \ge \lambda_2 |S| (1-|S|/|V(H_n)|)=2\cdot 2^{n-1}\cdot(1-2^{n-1}/2^n)=2^{n-1},$$
as required.

One reference which seems to have all of this, with some more detail, is [Alexandra Kolla's lecture notes](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs598ak/sp2012/Lecture3.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for an interesting solution. I have not studied the graph theory, but I was able to understand it in general terms. I know that combinatorics and graph theory are connected. But here it is at such a depth... It is impressive!

Answer (score 1):

Let's reformulate this problem as follows: prove that a randomly chosen edge is bichromatic (has ends of different colors) with probability of at least $1/n$.

Instead of picking a random edge directly, you can equivalently first pick two random antipodal vertices ($x$ and $\neg x$) of the hypercube, then pick a random $n$-edge path between them, and then pick a random edge from that path.

There are two cases: either $x$ and $\neg x$ are of the same color or not. If they are not of the same color, then at least one edge on any $n$-edge path between them is bichromatic. So the chance that a randomly chosen edge on that path is bichromatic is at least $1/n$.

The second case is when $x$ and $\neg x$ of the same color, for example, both are white. Let’s divide the set of vertices in the hypercube into layers. Layer $k$ will consist of all vertices with the Hamming distance $k$ from $x$. Since there are the same number of black and white vertices, and white has already been used for $x$ and $\neg x$, at least one of these layers, say layer $k$, will have more than half of its vertices black. Choosing a random $n$-edge path from $x$ to $\neg x$ is equivalent to choosing a random vertex $y$ from layer $k$, and then choosing a random $k$-edge path from $x$ to $y$, and a random $(n-k)$-edge path from $y$ to $\neg x$. If vertex $y$ is black (probability $> 1/2$), then since both $x$ and $\neg x$ are white, each of the paths $x$-to-$y$ and $y$-to-$\neg x$ contains a bichromatic edge. So with probability $> 1/2$, there are at least 2 bichromatic edges on a path from $x$ to $\neg x$, which means that the expected number of bichromatic edges on such a path is $> 1$. This means that a random edge on such a path is bichromatic with probability $> 1/n$.

What colorings achieve the $1/n$ lower bound? Since the second case ($x$ and $\neg x$ same color) results in the probability $> 1/n$, colorings that achieve the lower bound have all antipodal pairs of vertices of different colors. Moreover, any $n$-edge path between such vertices has exactly 1 bichromatic edge. This is a pretty strong condition because given any two (bichromatic) edges that flip different bits, one can find a pair of antipodal points and an $n$-edge path between them where both edges occur. This means that colorings that achieve the lower bound have bichromatic edges all flipping the same bit. This means that the only colorings that achieve the lower bound are colorings that are based on the value of the bit at some fixed index.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks. Perhaps this will work. So far, it is not entirely clear to me how to take into account that many different paths can pass through the same bichromatic edge. This interferes with this probabilistic construction.

Comment: Describing the set of n-edge-paths between antipodal points that contain a given edge seems indeed non-trivial. But I don't think this is needed here. All that is needed, it seems to me, is that the random edge sampling described in the 2nd paragraph of my answer is equivalent to uniform edge sampling. Is the validity of this equivalence that is your concern here?

Comment: Here's a sketch of my reasoning. Let a "rotation" of a hypercube mean any of its symmetries (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/15457/643521). The edge sampling method in 2nd paragraph is rotation-agnostic, that is, the effect is the same on the original hypercube and on any of its rotations. Also, using the generators of this symmetry group, it's not difficult to convince oneself that this group is edge-transitive, that is you can transform any edge into any other edge by rotating the hypercube. These two facts together imply that all edges should be selected with the same probability.

Comment: Intuitively, I can agree with your answer. But I still do not quite understand its formal construction. You are considering a probability space of edges that make up paths. You get >1/n probability that a random edge of each path is bichromatic. OK.

Comment: To complete the solution, you need to move to another probability space of arbitrary cube edges. You want to say that out of n randomly chosen edges of the cube, at least 1 is bichromatic. You argue this with considerations of symmetry. Intuitively I agree, but I don't trust my intuition.